# ParagraphVectors in deeplearning4j

Tags: deep-learning

I am new in utilizing deeplearning4j. I am running the paragraphvector classifier on a dataset including labeled and unlabeled data, and got a result. When I run it again on the same dataset using a same configuration, I will get another results! The new results is close to the previous one, but why it generates slightly different results?! What I mean by slighltly different results is like at the first run, it detects and assigns two testing samples to the first class we have, and in the second run, it assigns those two samples or probably one of them to another class. It happens normally for just one or two maybe three samples. Maybe I needed to inform you in advance that we have three classes that they are all related to cancer types diseases. 
Any hint/help/advice would be highly appreciated.

I use such a below configuration:

```
paragraphVectors = new ParagraphVectors.Builder()
.learningRate(0.2)
.minLearningRate(0.001)
.windowSize(2)
.iterations(3)
.batchSize(500)
.workers(4)
.stopWords(stopWords())
.minWordFrequency(10)
.layerSize(100)
.epochs(1)
.iterate(iterator)
.trainWordVectors(true)
.tokenizerFactory(tokenizerFactory)
.build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem turned out to be bad input with the tokenizer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am using StemmingPreprocessor rather than CommonPreprocessor to tackle the tokenization part. What do you mean by bad input?

Comment: I am also overriding the StemminPreprocessor as follows to convert consecutive digits to blank spaces: @Override  
     public String preProcess(String token) {
         token = token.toLowerCase();
         String base = super.preProcess(token);
         base = base.replaceAll("\\d+.*", "");
         return base;
     }